# How can I find the right complexity for the python code

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

What is the complexity for the following,

In my understanding it suppose to be for inside for, so `n**2`.
But I understand it is `n**3`.
Which is right?

```
n=int(input())
L=[]
for i in range (n):
    for j in range (n):
        L.append(i*j)
for i in range (n):
    l=L[:]+[i]
```

Comment: Please put your code into 'code 'section. It is really unclean what your sample program does.

Comment: `L` has `n**2` elements, and you create `n` copies of it in the last loop, so for me it's `n**3` total complexity.

Comment: Note that the final loop is bogus – ``l`` gets repeatedly overwritten on each iteration, and will just end up as ``l = L[:] + [n-1]``. The loop is redundant here (as is making a copy of ``L`` via ``L[:]`` – ``+`` already copies all elements from its operands). This is very likely not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of shallow list copying—examples are list.copy() or slicing list[:] — is linear to the number of elements in the list. For n list elements, the time complexity is O(n). Why? Because Python goes over all elements in the list and adds a copy of the object reference to the new list (copy by reference).

When you run:

```
for i in range (n):
    l=L[:]+[i]
```

the code runs `n * len(L)` times. because `L` is `n*n` long, it will be `n*n*n`
or `O(n**3)`.

Comment: Might be worth noting that ``L + [i]`` would also be O(n**2), since ``+(:list, :list)`` already copies all elements from both operands into a new list.